# Concatenate mutiple row data in one row seperated by comma

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, string-concatenation

I have a single table that I want to merge same questions to their answers. The answer to the question needs to be separated by a comma

```
tbl_data
Userid       question           answer      email
1032         Marital status     Single      Something@something.com
1032         Requirements       eco house   Something@something.com
1032         Requirements       garage      Something@something.com
1032         requirements       garden      Something@something.com
1032         Household income?  over 80k    Something@something.com
1033         Martial status     Married     harry@something.com
```

I would like to view the data like this and combine the requirements question and answers

```
tbl_data
    Userid       question           answer                    email
    1032         Marital status     Single                    Something@something.com
    1032         Requirements       eco house,garage,garden   Something@something.com
    1032         Household income?  over 80k                  Something@something.com
    1033         Martial status     Married                   harry@something.com
```

I have tried the solution here but without any luck as it just add all the answers for the questions against every answer [Attempted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470778/concatenate-multiple-data-rows-into-one-row)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Or better yet, just Google your data base name and "string aggregation".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Userid, GROUP_CONCAT(question SEPARATOR ',') as questions, answer, email FROM tbl_data GROUP BY question;
```

Comment: Hi @lubilis Thanks but i am using SQL 2008 it doesn't recognize GROUP_CONCAT and SEPERATOR functions

Comment: @Russell I added the sql-server-2008 tag to your question so you can have more specific answers

Comment: Thanks i will keep that in mind when i post in the future.